# Catch a cancelled stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cancellation

I have a stored procedure in SQL server that looks something like this:

```
insert into Record(StartTimestamp) values (GETDATE())
SET @MyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
begin try
  -- do something
  UPDATE Record SET EndTimestamp = GETDATE() WHERE ID = @MyID
end try
begin catch
  UPDATE Record SET EndTimestamp = GETDATE(), Error = ERROR_MESSAGE() WHERE ID = @MyID
end catch
```

It gets called from an application and takes a few seconds to run. If a user cancels it while it's running I end up with a StartTimestamp in the Record table but no error and no EndTimestamp. I always want to know that the user initiated this stored proc but I also want to always record when it finished, either by success, error, or being cancelled.

Is there any way to do that in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could rework the cancellation logic? So instead of calling SqlCommand.Cancel from the business layer execute some second proc that sets a flag somewhere, then have the first proc check for that flag while it's running...

The whole point of SqlCommand.Cancel is that it really stops execution, stopping the SP from running and doing a rollback. I think you'll have to approach this from the business layer.

GJ

Comment: I think you're probably right, but I don't own the business layer so I was hoping to be able to do it from my side.